# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. (laravel)

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel. And i've done researches but i can't seem to find the right     answer for my code.

So i have this controller

```
namespace Modules\Inventory\Http\Controllers;

use Modules\Setup\Init;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use Modules\Inventory\Entities\mongodb_logs as mongodb_logs;

use Modules\Template;

class ActivityLogsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * @return Response
     */
    protected $data;
    protected $page_title = 'Login';

    function setup($vars = null)
    {
        $Init = new Init;
        $vars['page'] = $this->page_title;
        $this->data['template'] = $Init->setup($vars);
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $loglists = mongodb_logs::orderBy('date_added', 'desc')->get();
        $this->data['loglist'] = $loglists;

        return view('inventory::_logs', $this->setup());
    }
}
```

and my view was just this simple

```
<table id="tbl_logs" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>User</td>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Message</td>
            <td>Before</td>
            <td>After</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if($loglist != null)
            @foreach($loglist as $logs)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$logs->type}}</td>
                    <td>{{$logs->logged_in_user}}</td>
                    <td>{{$logs->date_added}}</td>
                    <td>{{$logs->message}}</td>
                    <td>{{$logs->before}}</td>
                    <td>{{$logs->after}}</td>
                </tr>
             @endforeach
         @endif
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I retrieve the loglist from my mongodb collection 'logs'. I successfully retrieved the data you can try it via 'print_r' but when i view it on my view, this is the error that shows

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

this is the print_r result of my $loglist which i successfulyl retrieved from mongodb
[print_r result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C52FU.png)

here's a few lines of my var_dump.

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#408 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(40) {
    [0]=>
    object(Modules\Inventory\Entities\mongodb_logs)#409 (26) {
      ["connection":protected]=>
      string(7) "mongodb"
      ["collection":protected]=>
      string(4) "logs"
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(3) "_id"
      ["parentRelation":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["table":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["keyType":protected]=>
      string(3) "int"
      ["incrementing"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["with":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["perPage":protected]=>
      int(15)
      ["exists"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["attributes":protected]=>
      array(11) {
        ["_id"]=>
        object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID)#288 (1) {
          ["oid"]=>
          string(24) "58acfb2b202f941b50002ddf"
        }
        ["user_id"]=>
        int(2)
        ["admin_id"]=>
        int(2)
        ["logged_in_user"]=>
        string(5) "admin"
        ["date_added"]=>
        string(19) "2017-02-22 02:44:59"
        ["type"]=>
        string(6) "update"
        ["message"]=>
        string(69) "Deceased Documents ofAniyah Gottlieb ID number 4          successfully updated"
        ["before"]=>
        string(188) "    {"id":2,"d_id":4,"death_cert_no":null,"trans_permit_no":null,"crem_permit_no":nu    ll,"exhum_permit_no":null,"senior_card_no":null,"disabled_card_no":null,"created    _at":null,"updated_at":null}"
        ["after"]=>
        string(211) "        {"id":2,"d_id":4,"death_cert_no":"20171542","trans_permit_no":null,"crem_permit_    no":null,"exhum_permit_no":null,"senior_card_no":null,"disabled_card_no":null,"c    reated_at":null,"updated_at":"2017-02-22 02:44:59"}"
        ["updated_at"]=>
        object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#287 (1) {
          ["milliseconds"]=>
      string(10) "1672815231"
    }
    ["created_at"]=>
    object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#286 (1) {
      ["milliseconds"]=>
      string(10) "1672815231"
    }
  }
  ["original":protected]=>
  array(11) {
    ["_id"]=>
    object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID)#288 (1) {
      ["oid"]=>
      string(24) "58acfb2b202f941b50002ddf"
    }
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["admin_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["logged_in_user"]=>
    string(5) "admin"
    ["date_added"]=>
    string(19) "2017-02-22 02:44:59"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "update"
    ["message"]=>
    string(69) "Deceased Documents ofAniyah Gottlieb ID number 4 successfully updated"
    ["before"]=>
    string(188) "{"id":2,"d_id":4,"death_cert_no":null,"trans_permit_no":null,"crem_permit_no":null,"exhum_permit_no":null,"senior_card_no":null,"disabled_card_no":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}"
    ["after"]=>
    string(211) "{"id":2,"d_id":4,"death_cert_no":"20171542","trans_permit_no":null,"crem_permit_no":null,"exhum_permit_no":null,"senior_card_no":null,"disabled_card_no":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":"2017-02-22 02:44:59"}"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#287 (1) {
      ["milliseconds"]=>
      string(10) "1672815231"
    }
    ["created_at"]=>
    object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#286 (1) {
      ["milliseconds"]=>
      string(10) "1672815231"
    }
  }
```

Comment: on which line ?         replace your if condition @if(!empty($loglist))

Comment: Show us your printed array...

Comment: Hi @rahul_m , there's no specific line specified. the error just said

ErrorException in helpers.php line 532:
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\laragon\www\template\Modules\Inventory\Resources\views\_logs.blade.php)

I tried your suggestion but i still get the error

Comment: if you remove that foreach block is it working ?

Comment: firstly you print your $loglist array on view

Comment: What are the storage types you are using for your columns? Can you post that? Any column from your database maybe holding array or something else (which can't be parsed) It would be causing this error.

Comment: @rahul_m yes, the page displays but when i return the code block back, the error shows.

Comment: dump your `$loglist` and post here

Comment: Try removing every single line, of that td, and check which line causing error, surely, some of the value is array

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham i only have the simplest data, i only use date and strings.

Comment: if you keep <td>{{$logs->type}}</td> only out of all td is it working ?

Comment: @rahul_m they're all not working if i leave even just one <td>.. but if i remove them all, the page successfully loads without the values

Comment: <?php dd($logs); ?> and check what you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Your before and after variables are array that's why you getting this error. Try this code:

```
<tbody>
        @if($loglist != null)
            @foreach($loglist as $logs)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$logs->type}}</td>
                    <td>{{$logs->logged_in_user}}</td>
                    <td>{{$logs->date_added}}</td>
                    <td>{{$logs->message}}</td>
                    @foreach($logs->before as $before)
                    <td>{{$before->whatStringYouWant}}</td>
                    @endforeach
                    @foreach($logs->after as $after)
                    <td>{{$after->whatStringYouWant}}</td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
             @endforeach
         @endif
    </tbody>
```

Comment: oh! my before and after is json_encoded. But even if i remove them from the table view, i still get the error

Comment: Ok it seems `before and after` is not problem. Let's see other than this. What is the `$this->data['template'] = $Init->setup($vars)`

Comment: I'm doing all of these in a specific module where i use a template for blade view. The values from the controller is recognized to the view via '$this->data['name_in_view'] = name_in_controller', and all of the '$this->data' is contained inside '$this->setup()' for easier transfer of values bet. controller and views.

Comment: I think your array is multiple so please look inside foreach and pint the `$logs`.

Comment: Thank you, i'll check on it when i get home and reply back the result :)

Answer (score 0):

One or more of the returned object properties is array. try to `var_dump($logs)`

**I can't comment yet**